# Holomorphic Function in Disk and its Maximal

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Given a complex-valued function $f(z)$ holomorphic in $|z|<2$. Prove that $$\max_{|z|=1} \left|f(z)-\frac{1}{z}\right|\geq1$$

I know the behaviour of holomorphic function but I can't do so much about that. Please help me.

Comment: Perhaps there's an 'easy' way to show there exists $|z_0|<1$ such that $| f(z_0)-1/z_0| \ge 1$, and then apply the maximum modulus principle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let
$$
c = \max_{|z|=1} \left| f(z)-\frac 1z \right|.
$$
Then
$$
\left|\int_{|z|=1} \left(f(z) - \frac1z\right)\,dz \right| \le 2\pi c
$$
by the standard estimation lemma. On the other hand (by Cauchy's integral theorem and/or formula), 
$$
\int_{|z|=1} \left(f(z) - \frac1z\right)\,dz = -2\pi i
$$
so $c \ge 1$.