# polynomial approximations of $1/z$ on the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, maximum-principle

I want to show that there exist an $\epsilon \geq 0$
$$ \max_{z \in C(0,1)} \left| p(z)-\frac{1}{z}\right|\geq \epsilon $$
for every polynomial $p(z)$, where $C(0,1)$ denotes the unit circle.

Approach: I tried a proof by contradiction. So suppose
$$ \max_{z \in C(0,1)} \left| p(z)-\frac{1}{z}\right|= 0. $$ 
Then $|zp(z)-1|=0$ on $C(0,1)$. According to maximum modulus principle $zp(z)-1$ is constant (since $zp(z)-1$ cannot attain a maximum in the unit disc $D(0,1)$). Hence $p(z)=1/z$ on the punctured plane, contradiction. Is this the correct reasoning? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is $C(0,1)$? If I understand correctly, $D(0,1)$ is the unit disk?

Comment: I made the edit. It's indeed the unit circle and unit disc.

Comment: seems good to me, but complex analysis is not my specialty

Comment: Okay thanks for reading! Hopefully, someone can affirm that's indeed correct?

Comment: Your proof starts off incorrectly. All you would know is that for every $\epsilon>0,$ there is $p_\epsilon$ such that $\max_{C(0,1)} |p_\epsilon(z)-1/z| < \epsilon.$

Comment: I think $\epsilon = 0$ works obviously unless the inequalites are modified.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2105919 for another approach